# Why does new Job() throw java.lang.IllegalStateException: Job in state DEFINE instead of RUNNING?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Trying to write data to [Parquet](http://parquet.incubator.apache.org/) in [Spark 1.1.1](https://spark.apache.org/).

I am following [A Powerful Big Data Trio: Spark, Parquet and Avro](http://zenfractal.com/2013/08/21/a-powerful-big-data-trio/) as a template. The code in the article uses a job setup in order to call the method to ParquetOutputFormat API.

```
scala> import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job 
scala> val job = new Job() 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Job in state DEFINE instead of RUNNING
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.ensureState(Job.java:283)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.toString(Job.java:452)
    at scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime$.scala$runtime$ScalaRunTime$$inner$1(ScalaRunTime.scala:324)
    at scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime$.stringOf(ScalaRunTime.scala:329)
    at scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime$.replStringOf(ScalaRunTime.scala:337)
    at .<init>(<console>:10)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    ...
```

Comment: Why are you trying to create a MapReduce job?

Comment: ok, i explained in more details -

Comment: no nothing to do with mapreduce. Please read my updated post.

Comment: Can you confirm the answer?

Comment: One work-around described at http://markmail.org/message/x77s57w47homqn6x is to wrap the Job code in a method so that the Spark shell doesn't try to call it's toString() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark job and MapReduce job are different and Spark uses MapReduce's InputFormat to get input in HDFS.

From the stack trace, the error comes from toString method. Try running the job with spark-submit, not spark-shell. It should resolve the error from toString.

Comment: Added a paragraph for explanation.

Comment: This is not an answer. You can use `mapreduce.Job` to specify different Hadoop `InputFormat`s for Spark, and you use the `Job` class for it. That's why the OP is using the `Job` class.